# ruby selenium web driver - get google knowledge graph content

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, selenium, web-scraping

I am using ruby selenium web driver and trying to get content of google knowledge graph which locates on the top right-hand site from search results on the first google search results page in the `<div class="xpdopen">`

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
@driver.get "http://google.com"
element = @driver.find_element :name => "q"
element.send_keys "BMW"
element.submit
content = @driver.find_element(:class, 'xpdopen')
```

But selenium can not find this element and rises error

```
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name 'xpdopen'"
```

When I tried in a chrome js console `$('.xpdopen')` it found this element straight away

I also have tried

`@driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('xpdopen');")`

but it can not find this element

I also tied `@driver.page_source` and  `<div class="xpdopen">` not in the page source but I can see it in the chrome console. Why?

How can I get this element  with selenium?

Here are results what I am getting from pry:

```
[21] pry(main)> @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..f822d288ec7f0a708 browser=:phantomjs>
[22] pry(main)> @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10    
=> 10
[23] pry(main)> @driver.get "http://google.com"    
=> {}
[24] pry(main)> element = @driver.find_element :name => "q"    
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f389f4a8876f601e id=":wdc:1434526425103">
[25] pry(main)> element.send_keys "BMW"    
=> nil
[26] pry(main)> element.submit    
=> {}
[27] pry(main)> sleep 10    
=> 10
[28] pry(main)> content = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="rhs_block"]/ol/li/div[1]/div')    
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//*[@id=\"rhs_block\"]/ol/li/div[1]/div'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"67","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:8929","User-Agent":"Ruby"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"xpath\",\"value\":\"//*[@id=\\\"rhs_block\\\"]/ol/li/div[1]/div\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/2f3cf350-14c3-11e5-9f8e-4173e8049986/element"}} (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException)
```

and

```
[29] pry(main)> content = @driver.find_element(:css, "#rhs_block > ol > li > div.kp-blk._Jw._Rqb._RJe > .xpdopen")
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with css selector '#rhs_block > ol > li > div.kp-blk._Jw._Rqb._RJe > .xpdopen'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"113","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:8929","User-Agent":"Ruby"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"css selector\",\"value\":\"#rhs_block \\u003e ol \\u003e li \\u003e div.kp-blk._Jw._Rqb._RJe \\u003e .xpdopen\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/2f3cf350-14c3-11e5-9f8e-4173e8049986/element"}} (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException)
```

and just to demonstrate that it is finding other elements on the same page without problems:

```
[30] pry(main)> results = @driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//p/a") 
=> [#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x6f6a74631e2b7010 id=":wdc:1434527087873">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x7b6d276448081688 id=":wdc:1434527087874">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f9504a4171b03970a id=":wdc:1434527087875">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fa6e0158aa8d24e2a id=":wdc:1434527087876">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x327bf842e4399368 id=":wdc:1434527087877">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..fae292d7ca211ab32 id=":wdc:1434527087878">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x129a58eb5ed6ee9c id=":wdc:1434527087879">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x46ef3b45800e63e0 id=":wdc:1434527087880">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x26bfb47f8ad498ea id=":wdc:1434527087881">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f03756c2924a2974 id=":wdc:1434527087882">,
 #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0xfba93aab4b32af8 id=":wdc:1434527087883">]
```

I took screenshot with and found out that phantomjs does not display (does not have content) knowledge graph

**Screenshot from phantomjs**

[image: phantomjs page content]

**Screenshot from Firefox**
[image: Firefox page content]

Why phantomjs does not have content knowledge graph?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently css won't know where to find xpdopen class by it's own, you have to give the entire path to the element:

Xpath:

```
content = @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id="rhs_block"]/ol/li/div[1]/div")
```

Css:

```
content = @driver.find_element(:css, "#rhs_block > ol > li > div.kp-blk._Jw._Rqb._RJe > .xpdopen")
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I tried your solution and it gives same error and not funding xpdopen element.

Comment: I've tried it and it worked for me... can you make sure you wait for the search to be complete prior to attempting to map the element? or even better, use binding.pry right before the step that fails, make sure everything is loaded and try to manually map the element in your command line... let us know the result

Comment: I just eded results from pry to my question

Comment: Can not find out what is a problem here

Comment: Ok! Found issue! Problem was that  I use phantomjs and it does not display knowledge graph. You probobly used Firefox that is why it worked for you? May be you know why phantomjs does not display it and how to fix it?

Comment: Let me try with phantomjs sec

Comment: phantomjs is probably building the structure differently, which sucks... is there a reason why you can't map the parent div, which wraps the div you were initially trying to fetch? try content = @driver.find_element(:css, "#rhs_block")... that should give you the parent div... if that's not enough and you really need to map that particular div, then we will need to learn how phantomjs is structuring the html to find the correct path

Comment: It will be not possible to find correct path in this case as phantomjs does not have content "knowledge graph", I just added screen shots from firefox and phantomjs where we can see it missing on the screenshot from phantomjs.